# See What Line a Function Was Called From in Python Decorator

Tags: python, decorator, inspect

Given something like this:

```
@my_decorator
my_function(some, args)
```

Is it possible for my_decorator to discover the file and line number my_function was called from?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible for the *decorator*, only for the *decorated function* (i.e. the decorator's return value). I suppose that's what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarifying that, I've been a bit confused about the terminology surrounding decorators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`traceback.extract_stack()` will allow you to examine the current stack frame.